# Swift TextField Restriction with decimals and length

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am trying to add character limit restrictions on both textFields. I also am limiting decimal input to only one decimal which seems to be working fine. My character limit is causing many errors. Whats the best way to do this?

```
        func textField(_ textField: UITextField,shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,replacementString string: String) -> Bool
        {
            let characterLimit = 8
            let countdotsStockPrice = (stockPrice.text?.components(separatedBy: ".").count)! - 1
            let countdotsCapitalInvested = (capitalInvested.text?.components(separatedBy: ".").count)! - 1

            //TextField1: stockPrice.text
            let currentString: NSString = (stockPrice.text ?? "") as NSString
            let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

                 //TextField2: capitalInvested.text
                let currentStringCapital: NSString = (capitalInvested.text ?? "") as NSString
                let newStringCapital = currentStringCapital.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)



            if textField == stockPrice {

                if (newString.characters.count >= characterLimit) {
                    stockPrice.deleteBackward()
                }

                if countdotsStockPrice > 0 && string == "." { return false} else {return true}

            } else if textField == capitalInvested {



                if (newStringCapital.characters.count >= characterLimit) {
                    capitalInvested.deleteBackward()
                }


                if countdotsCapitalInvested > 0 && string == "." { return false} else {return true}

            }

            if textField == stockPrice || textField == capitalInvested {



            }
            return true
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // check decimal restriction
    let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789")) == nil

    if !replacementStringIsLegal {
        return false
    }
    let nsString = textField.text as NSString?
    let newString = nsString!.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    // check maximum length
    if newString.characters.count > 4 {
        return false
    }
    return true

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: your ! doesnt need to be there but thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can archive this like this:

```
private let decimalSeparator = "."

func isFractionalPartValid(in string: String) -> Bool {
    let maxFractionalPartLength = 1
    guard let separator = decimalSeparator.characters.first,
        let comaIndex = string.characters.index(of: separator),
        string.distance(from: comaIndex, to: string.endIndex) > maxFractionalPartLength + 1 else {
            return true
    }
    return false
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let set = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: decimalSeparator)).inverted
    let maxLength = 8
    let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
    let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    if newString.characters.count > maxLength || newString.rangeOfCharacter(from: set) != nil {
        return false
    }
//Below is not required but possibly you need it ;)
    if newString.characters.count == maxLength && newString.characters.last == decimalSeparator.characters.first {
        return false
    }

    return isFractionalPartValid(in: newString)
}
```

But honestly, I think you should move this logic to some another object